# Bootstrap same width for labels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3. I have 5 different `label`s and I want to set their `width` to the maximum one and center the text.

[image]

For example every `label`'s `width` should be equal to red one.

```
<span class="label label-md label-danger">Merkez Tarafından Reddedildi</span>
```

Comment: you can add col-*-* along with label classes to adjust the widths of the label.

Comment: I tried but this time they won't be `label-md`, they will be `label-sm`.

Comment: specify the min and max width for all the labels

Comment: Guys if you want you can give answer for this and I can check one of this for solved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because `.label` is an inline element, you must set as `inline-block` and then set a `min-width`

The bootstrap already centers the text in `.label` so no need to worry about that.

**Note:** I've used `!important` just for the demo, avoid at all cost using in your code.

```css
.label {
  min-width: 200px !important;
  display: inline-block !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="label label-md label-danger">Merkez Tarafından Reddedildi</span>
<hr />
<span class="label label-md label-info">Merkez</span>
<hr />
<span class="label label-md label-warning">Merkez Tarafından </span>
<hr />
<span class="label label-md label-success">Tarafından Reddedildi</span>
<hr />
<span class="label label-md label-default">Tarafından</span>
<hr />
<span class="label label-md label-primary">Tarafından lipsum</span>
```

Comment: Utilizing `!important` is totally unnecessary demo or otherwise: `.label.label-md`.

Comment: Also it's only min width, if there is more text then the boxes wont be the same width.

Comment: @Frutis, the `min-width` won't work in inline elements,

Comment: @vanburen I am more than aware of CSS specificity and I knew I could use that, but that selector couldn't be practical for the user, imagine that the user has `label-sm` instead the selector would fail, that's why I had to use a general selector knowing that the stack snippet doesn't load very well the CSS (order) but explaining why I used `!important` and why should the  user **NOT** use it

Comment: @vanburen just even look at the OP comment ***I tried but this time they won't be `label-md`, they will be `label-sm`*** so  yes I used a general selector instead, explaining and advising.

Comment: @dippas I never stated you're unaware of **specificity** or anything else which is to the point, others who read this are likely to not take your warning into account so I believe it would be better to suggest the use of another class and explain that as an example as opposed to using an example that you yourself suggest to _avoid at all cost using in your code_.

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of the exact answer you want, but maybe this will be even better for you.

```
.label {
    width:200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.label:hover {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Dunno then, works fine for me. Maybe width is too high for you to see the difference on how it will look if there is more text. The idea behind this is to set fixed width and if there is more content it will expand on hover.